# In the Change of Variables theorem, why must Dg be invertible a.e.?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, jacobian, change-of-variable

> **Theorem:** (Change of Variables Theorem). Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a region and let $U$ be an open set containing $\Omega$ so that ${\bf g}:U\to\Bbb R^n$ is one-to-one and ${\cal C}^1$ with invertible derivative at each point. Suppose $f:{\bf g}(\Omega)\to\Bbb R$ and $(f\circ{\bf g})\lvert\det D{\bf g}\rvert:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ are both integrable. Then
>   $$\int_{{\bf g}(\Omega)}f({\bf y}) \operatorname d\!V_{\bf y} = \int_\Omega(f\circ{\bf g})(x) \lvert\det D{\bf g}\rvert \operatorname d\!V_{\bf x}.$$
>
> **Remark** . One can strengthen the theorem, in particular by allowing $D{\bf g}(x)$ to fail to be invertible on a set of volume $0$. This is important for many applications—e.g., polar, cylindrical, and spherical coordinates. But we won’t bother justifying it here.

What happens if $D{\bf g}(x)$ fails to be invertible on a set of positive measure? I can't come up with a counterexample in that case. Why is that hypothesis necessary?

Comment: To emphasize what's the issue that's bothering us: Suppose $D\mathbf{g}$ fails to be invertible on $K \subset \Omega$, the critical set of $\mathbf{g}$ in $\Omega$. As $\mathbf{g}$ is $C^1$, Sard's theorem should guarantee $\mathbf{g}(K)$ is measure zero. Then on the left side of the formula the integral vanishes over $\mathbf{g}(K)$ and on the right side of the formula the integral vanishes over $K$ (because $\det D\mathbf{g} = 0$ there). So it should reduce to the Change of Variables formula with $\Omega \setminus K$ instead of $\Omega$ as the region of interest. What goes wrong?

Comment: @BalarkaSen From Calculus on Manifolds by Spivak, pp. 71-72 : "The condition $det(g'(x)) \neq 0$ may be eliminated from the hypotheses of [the theorem] by using [Sard's theorem]", without any mention of measure $0$ or other hypotheses on said set. So à priori your argument holds... Where does the statement in the OP come from ? +1 for the interesting question.

Comment: The quote is from _Multivariable Mathematics: Linear Algebra, Multivariable Calculus, and Manifolds_ by Ted Shifrin. I imagine once he's done with Christmas celebrations he'll see this question and comment on it. @Bass

Comment: @Bass Thanks, I never thought about this generalization even though it's kind of patently obvious. In most of the cases in application $g$ is either a diffeomorphism or an almost-diffeomorphism anyway, as described in the remark, so it kind of threw me off. Thanks for verifying!

Comment: @BalarkaSen Wait- $\Omega$ is taken to be a "region", i.e. the closure of a bounded open set whose boundary has volume zero. There's no guarantee that $\Omega\setminus K$ is a region.

Comment: @Bass Is Spivak talking about Lebesgue integrals there? Ted's book is dealing with Riemann integrals here. Perhaps there is a counterexample after all, but instead of the sides of the equation being unequal, we just have one side left undefined.

Comment: Wow I have _zero_ memory of asking this question