# Conditions on change of variables for integral constructed as flow of ordinary differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, change-of-variable

Consider an integral
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int dt \int d^3 x f(x) h(t)
\end{equation}
and the change of variables $x=\phi(t,x')$, where
\begin{align}
\partial_t \phi(t,x')=F(\phi)\\
\phi(0,x')=x'.
\end{align}
In principle the change of variables is well defined on all points which are not critical for the vector field $F$. However, I'm pretty sure that if we adopt Lebesgue's definition of integrals and exclude all the critical points of $F$ from the integration (which should lie on zero measured surfaces, if $F$ is continuous), then under some regularity conditions on $F$, the integral is still well defined. More concretely, what I'm looking at, after the change of variables, is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\int dt \int d^3x' |\text{det}[\mathbb{J}_{x'}\phi]|f(\phi(t,x'))h(t).
\end{equation}
and I'm wondering what conditions (and why) need to be imposed on $F$ so that the change of variables is well defined and integration is convergent. Assume $f$ and $h$ are $L_2$, for simplicity.

Comment: Thm. 7.26 (pages 153-154) of Rudin's "Real and complex analysis" seems to suggest that the procedure is always well defined as long as the critical points lie on a zero measured set. Can someone confirm? This question seems to also be related to a certain extent to an older question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2579863/in-the-change-of-variables-theorem-why-must-dg-be-invertible-a-e